# How to retrieve recipients email and separate them with comma in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="contact">
  <div class="person">
     <div class="name">John</div>
     <div class="email"><a href="mailto:lorem01@yahoo.com">lorem01@yahoo.com</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="person">
     <div class="name">Grace</div>      
     <div class="email"><a href="mailto:lorem02@gmail.com">lorem02@gmail.com</a></div>
  </div>
</div>  


<input type="text" class="recipients" value="">
```

I wish to get the all the emails in the contact list, separate them with comma and output into a  field. The output in the field should be:

```
lorem01@yahoo.com, lorem02@gmail.com
```

I tried with the following jquery but no idea how to separate them with comma, hope you can help me to improve the code. Thanks.

```
  var emails = $('.contact .email').text();    
  $('input.recipients').val($.trim(emails));
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7fdzfrbr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery `.map()` to return all the email as jquery object. then convert into array using `.get()` and join with `,` to get intended result:

```
var emails = $('.contact .email').map(function(){
  return $(this).text()
}).get().join(',');    
$('input.recipients').val(emails);
```

### Working Demo